# What is the $f(x)$? How can I compute the $f$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f$ be a differential function on positive real number and $f(x)$ satisfies $f(x) = -2xf'(x)$. If $f(x)$ is not always zero, it is easy.
However, I don't know whether there is a point $a$ such that $f(a) = 0$.
In this condition, How to compute $f$?

Comment: Yes, I know. As stated, if $f(x) $ is not zero on positive real number, I can divide $f(x)$ for everywhere, but it is impossible because I don't know the kernel of $f.$

Comment: Clearly, $f(0)=0$.

Comment: well, f is defined on positive real number. f(0) is not defined

Comment: _Hint_: the differential equation is separable. Very easy to solve, and once that's done you'll notice something very surprising.

Comment: If there is such a point $a>0$, then $f'(a)=f(a)=0$, and you can use the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) to show that (as $x\mapsto 0$ is a solution to the differential equation with these initial conditions at $a$) $f=0$ on a maximal interval around $a$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel but the first step of solving a differential equation is dividing by $f(x)$.  As the OP points out, this is problematic if $f(x) = 0$ at any point.  The question is really: why is that first step okay?  How can we justify it?

Comment: One could solve this as an *exact equation*, thereby avoiding the issue of division

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand anything.

Comment: I made it!!!. I could think of $f(x)$ as $y$ and solve  ODE Thank you everyone.

Comment: @PiggyJin Please tell me if i answered your question or not.

Comment: Why would you need to "think of f(x) as y"?  Just changing what you call a function does not change the meaning.  You can do this as easily as $\frac{df(x)}{f(x)}= -2x dx$ or as $frac{dy}{dx}= -2xdx$.  The original point, that f(x) might be 0 for some x is better, but since derivatives are [b]limits[/b] not depending on the value at a particular point, it turns out we don't need to worry about that.

Comment: @Hamman I don't know how to choose I = R on your answer. Sorry

Comment: @user247327 I just used separate variables. Derivative does not depend on a just point. However, it depends on an interval. Because we don't have any information about $f(x)$, we need to check which points have a zero.

Comment: @PiggyJin i didn't choose $I=R$.Is it correct or no.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $f(x)\ne {0}$
 $$f(x)=-2xf'(x)\Rightarrow\\\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=-\frac1{2x}\Rightarrow\\(\ln f(x))'=\Big( \ln x^{-\frac12}\Big)=\Big( \ln \frac{1}{\sqrt x}\Big)'$$

It follows that $f(x)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{x}}$ where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: How can you deal with a f(x)=0 case? If you have a good answer, please tell me.

Comment: @PiggyJin Well, it is a trivial case. The statement $f(x) = -2xf'(x)$ is true for it, but it is of no interest. That is, for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ you have $f(x)=0$ as desired.

Comment: What I want to say is a kernel of the $f(x)$ is a small interval. I think we need to consider this cases

Answer (score 0):

Separate variables and on integration,

$f(x)=\frac{c}{√x}$, where $c$ is constant of integration. This solution exists for $x>0$.

However, $f(x)=0$ is a trivial solution.